# What apps script function do I need to make my chatbot capable of reading and writing to sheets for the whole domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I got a bit stuck.

**Goal:**
To have a chatbot that domain users can use to confirm shoppinglist that is kept in a google spreadsheets.

The sheet that holds the data is generated based on forms input and manual input.
I am looking for a chatbot because I wanted an interface that shows some basic in/output without sharing the whole spreadsheet.

**What have I done:**

I looked into service accounts and I am able to read data. I wanted a sheet object but I read that this is not possible. I get a JSON object. I will manage I think.

**How do I write data to the sheet?**
The code under here only reads it. What function sends the data to sheets?

```
/**
 * Configures the spreadsheet service.
 */
function getSpreasheetService() {
 return OAuth2.createService("spreadsheet")
 // Set the endpoint URL.
 .setTokenUrl("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token")
// Set the private key and issuer.
 .setPrivateKey(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY)
 .setIssuer(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
// Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
 .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
// Set the scope.
 .setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets");
}

function readSheet(){
  var service = getSpreasheetService();
  var ssId = 'sheetsid' ;
  var range = 'Voorraad!A1:50';
  var url = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' + ssId +'/values/' + range;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken() } }); //json data
  var rep = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var values =  rep.values;

console.log(response);
console.log(rep);
 




  //  Logger.log(values);
  //now i can use these data to reply back to end user as message
}
```

Comment: How many users in your entire domain?

Comment: For now there are 9

Answer (score 1):

Here we go I found a solution :)

```
/**
 * Configures the spreadsheet service.
 */
function getSpreasheetService() {
 return OAuth2.createService("spreadsheet")
 // Set the endpoint URL.
 .setTokenUrl("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token")
// Set the private key and issuer.
 .setPrivateKey(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY)
 .setIssuer(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
// Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
 .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
// Set the scope.
 .setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets");
}



function writeSheet(){
  var service = getSpreasheetService();
  var spreadsheetId = ' your spreadsheet id' ;
  var range = 'Blad1!A3'; // range = '[sheetname]![starting cell]:[ending cell]';

 var waardes = {values:[ ['A3 data' , 'B3 data', 'C3 data'] , [4, '', "C4"]] } ; 
//no matter if it is one value or rows with multiple values, it must be a nested json object. {values: [['value']]} 
// "" or '' work the same


// Method: spreadsheets.values.update
var url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + spreadsheetId + "/values/" + range + "?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED"; //valueInputOption is required
var params = {
  method: "put",
  headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + service.getAccessToken()},
  contentType: "application/json",
  payload: JSON.stringify(waardes),
};
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);


}
```

**I used these pages to find my answers:**

https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/third-party-apis
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest

Comment: Glad you found your answer, please consider editing it to make it more helpful for future users, namely making clear exactly what changes you had to make, and pulling in any helpful documentation from those links, so that if the links were to stop working the answer would still make sense :)